# get functions from old package

Tags: r, package

There are a number of packages that have functions I would like to use, however these packages are no longer maintained and were built for older R versions.

Using R 3.0.02 I get the following

```
install.packages("steepness")
Warning message:
package ‘steepness’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Similarly using

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/steepness/steepness_0.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, contriburl=NULL, type="source")
Warning message:
package ‘http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/steepness/steepness_0.2.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

and when i manually place the `steepness` folder in the `win-library`:

```
library(steepness)
Error: package ‘steepness’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

I only want a couple functions to save myself time rewriting everything from scratch. What is the best way round this? Can I just copy the source code for the two functions myself for example and define them myself? I have looked at the folder for the package but there is no obvious `.r` file to steal code from ONLY `.rdb` AND `.rdx` which are file formats I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some experience with defining functions in `R` you can just download the bundled `*.tar.gz` package from CRAN, look in the `R` folder of the unpacked package and extract the code you need.

Comment: cheers, i have done this but there are only `.rdx` and `.rdb` files, I am unfamiliar with these file types.

Comment: I have just done this and there are nice .R files in the subdirectory R.

Comment: `*.rdx` and `*.rdb` are binary files. Hence, it won't help you at all to look at them. Assuming you want to look at the source of http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/steepness/steepness_0.2.tar.gz you can download it from the homepage and untar the package. Then you should find a subfolder called `R` which contains the original `*.R` files. Relevant: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-July/075948.html